# Calling swing worker at different places with different parameters

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am using swing worker to validate files, 
I want the startLine and endLine to be sent to the validate class as i do not want to validate the whole file every time.  For the first time when an existing file is openend, i want to send the startLine as 0 and endLine as endLine = editorTextArea.getLineCount() - 1;.  After that i should be able to send the startLine and endLine to my convenience every second.  How do i achieve this?

Validate class:

```
  class Validate implements Runnable {

     private JTextArea editorTextArea;
     private JTextArea errorTextArea;
     private int startLine;
     private int endLine;

     public Validate(JTextArea editor, JTextArea error, startLine, endLine) {
         this.editorTextArea = editor;
         this.errorTextArea  = error;
         this.startLine = startLine;
         this.endLine = endLine;        
    }

@Override
public void run() {
    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            //CODE TO VALIDATE
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {                
            //CODE TO DISPLAY THE RESULT
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
    }
 }
```

Main class:

```
  //Calls the validate
   public void taskExecutor() {               
          ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                 Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
           final ScheduledFuture<?> timeHandle =
                 scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Validate(editorTextArea,   errorTextArea), 0, 1, SECONDS);                 
}


    private void openFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)      {                                      

  fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(".txt"));
int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new JPanel());
int totLines = 0;
String[] content = null;

if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    try {
        filename = String.valueOf(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
        setTitle(filename);

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
        editorTextArea.read(fr, null);
        fr.close();
        startLine = 0;
        endLine = editorTextArea.getLineCount() - 1;
        //here i want to call the validate class once. that is askExecutor();                
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) uses an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) internally, but the worker "is only designed to be executed once." I don't see why you're wrapping the worker in a `Runnable` that's scheduled at a fixed rate. Instead, `execute()` the task once and let it `publish()` interim results that can be `process()`ed on the EDT. For line numbers, `SwingWorker<Boolean, Integer>` may be appropriate. `Integer` would represent the last line number processed, while `Boolean` would represent the final validation result returned by `doInBackground()`.

If the user is aynchronously selecting multiple files for validation, consider adding each executing worker to a suitable `TableModel` and displaying the results in the corresponding `JTable`.  @mKorbel has shown several [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:714968%20%5Bjtable%5D%20jprogressbar) featuring `JProgressBar`.

Addendum: If you're validating *additions* to the `JTextArea`, you'll want to `execute()` a new worker each time, passing the new range of line numbers as parameters to the worker's constructor. This [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata), which passes a single `int count`, may suggest the approach. The trigger can be a `java.util.Timer`, a `javax.swing.Timer` or even the `ScheduledExecutorService` you originally proposed.

Comment: Thanks.  i removed the runnable, the scenario is, when the file is opened the file should be validated fully, i can do it by sending the line numbers, 0 and totallines.  But, From next time onwards, that is when the file is modified/corrected in jtextarea validations is done only to part which is visible in viewport.  On what event should i have to call the swingworker to validate, should i have to put in documentListener's insertUpdate method?

Comment: @FirmView: Ah, I misunderstood. It think pass the line numbers as parameters to the worker's constructor. More above.

Comment: i am upvoting for your effort.  I was asking on what event i should be calling the swing worker. first time, it will be in file open, then should i have to call it document listeners methods?

Comment: Good idea; a `DocumentEvent` would be exactly what the worker needs to do incremental validation.